# Post data with file upload Rest

Tags: php, rest, symfony, postman

For my rest API build with symfony, I have an entity Product with an image.

With Postman I try to post this entity and upload this file, I use form-data like I see on many post, with Content-Type form-data/multipart and without.

[POSTMAN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5enaw.png)

But my file doesn't appear in the body request. When I dump it I have only four parameters without " url_image " ?

What is the problem ? How can I fix it ?

Comment: add the controller code to the post please

Answer (score 0):

if you are doing:

```
public function someAction(Request $request) {
    $file = $request->get('url_image');
    // or
    $file = $request->request->get('url_image');
}
```

then you are doing it wrong, instead do:

```
public function someAction(Request $request) {
    /** @var \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile $file */
    $file = $request->files->get('url_image');
}
```

the uploaded files are not exactly in the request body

Answer (score 0):

When you upload a file via the method you described above, the file contents are not in the request body, but in the request's files parameter bag.

You can fetch them in your controller like this:

```
public function someControllerMethod(Request $request)
{
   $img = $request->files->get('url_image');
}
```

What you will be getting is an instance of UploadedFile. I recommend you to check the docs to learn how to work with it. 
You will usually move to a location in your file system or opening it as a stream and send it to a cloud storage provider.

Cheers!

Comment: Hummm ok, thanks ! But how can i validate this file with my form ? Because now i do basically a $form->submit($request->request->all ) for validate and persist my entity